# How can i take user input and save it permanently in a variable and use that variable in window.open()

Tags: javascript, if-statement, variables, url, user-input

I am trying to use javascript to take a url entered in a text box and permanently change a variable. I then want to use that variable in an if statement with window.open() if the condition is true. The code will be a file saved on their computer that they open in chrome. Any ideas?

Comment: This question is extremely vague.

Answer (score 0):

Save this variable in the localStorage (https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), but you must know it isn't pernament.

When user open page next time, you can get this variable via js.